# Restore script that was overwritten by Python/Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

i have a huge problem here: I accidently overwrite my Script with another one. Now all my work is lost. Is the any possibility to restore the old Script/Code? I'm using Spyder.

Comment: No, not really since Spyder uses iPython underneath the hood so if you overwrote the file physically on the disk, there is no possibility to turn it back. Maybe you still have the correct file version in the Spyder's memory. Try to look around the variables.

Comment: If you are on Windows then you might be able to restore it from a previous version (this isn't Spyder specific).

Comment: I'm on windows. But how do i do that?

Comment: [This](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/restoring-files-from-windows-10s-file-history/) might help. I've never done this, so have no idea if it will work.